# SQL query run going over CPU usage limit

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this SQl:

```
Select b. Date, count(b. Name) from
(Select date, name, order_no from table1 where date = ‘2020-01-31’ and order_no not in ( select order_no from table1where date < ‘2020-01-31’)) b
Inner join
( select name from table2 where date1< ‘2020-01-31’)a
On a. Name= b. Name group by 1
UNION

Select b. Date, count(b. Name) from
(Select date, name, order_no from table1 where date = ‘2020-02-28’ and order_no not in ( select order_no from table1where date < ‘2020-02-28’)) b
Inner join
( select name from table2 where date1< ‘2020-02-28’)a
On a. Name= b. Name group by 1
UNION

Select b. Date, count(b. Name) from
(Select date, name, order_no from table1 where date = ‘2020-03-31’ and order_no not in ( select order_no from table1where date < ‘2020-03-31’)) b
Inner join
( select name from table2 where date1< ‘2020-03-31’)a
On a. Name= b. Name group by 1
UNION
...... until ‘2020-12-31’
```

Taking too much CPU.
Any help? Mostly I am trying to take orders and names of customers which are new to each month from table1 and then checking these customer names if they existed before a that month in table2. Table 2 is history table so huge and does not have date1 field.
Thanks for any help in here

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, provide aa *clear* explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: I mentioned that I am trying to get new orders and associated customer names for each month from Table1 and then cross check those customer names against history table2 if they existed before that month, so basically trying to see how many of customers from new orders are already existing.

Comment: . . .I don't see that at all.  You are only looking at one date per month in `table1`.

Comment: Table1 is monthly table where whole month data comes as month end data.

Comment: Your explanantion & SQL is confusing. You compare order_no in your subquery, but this is usually unique, can you add more details? Getting new customers for each month can easily be done using row_number instead of those Unions. Similar for table2 and then it's a single join plus count

Comment: Our table1 is structured such a way that all the active orders come there as month last date. So all active orders until Feb 29 th and before all would be as Feb 29 th row and all active orders until Jan31st and before would be in Jan31st rows. And this table has data starting from Jan 2020. Basically, active orders from Jan31st would be in Feb 29 rows also. That’s why I did the sub query first to find new orders that have been added new for each month, from there associated customers and then to history table which has customer data for last 10 years to find existing customer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
with t1 as 
 (
    Select datecol -- already last day of month
      ,name
    from table1
    qualify
       row_number() -- oldest row per name, i.e. new in this month
       over (partition by name 
             order by datecol) = 1
 ),
t2 as 
 (
    Select last_day(datecol) as datecol -- last day of month
      ,name
    from table2
    qualify
       row_number() -- oldest row 
       over (partition by name 
             order by datecol) = 1
 )
select t2.datecol, count(*)
from t1 join t2
  on t1.name = t2.name       -- same customer
 and t1.datecol > t2.datecol -- older row exists
group by 1
order by 1
```